# How to create a new page in order to display a big file?

Tags: minipage, minted

I use [minted](https://fr.sharelatex.com/learn/Code_Highlighting_with_minted) to display my source code with Latex like this:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
\color{white}{\inputminted[bgcolor=bg]{python}{chapitre1/mybigscript.py}}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
```

My source code is huge and take more than 5 pages. It is painful to cut my python file in other file to display correctly my source code on Latex.

Do you have a solution to generate a new page automatically when the file is too huge?

Comment: Why do you use minipage? I think the question you intend to ask is not “how to create a new page automatically” (that is something TeX does by default), but probably something like how to typeset code that spans multiple pages, using `minted`. (To which the answer probably starts with “don't use minipage”… but it's hard to answer without clear requirements stated in the question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behaviour of `minted` is to start a new page when the current one is full, but the `minipage` avoids this. So you have to avoid the `minipage`.

I think the purpose of the `minipage` was to reduce the width of the code. To do this without avoiding pagebreaks, you can use `adjustwidth` of the `changepage` package:

Add

```
\usepackage{changepage}
```

to your preamble and then write

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{.1\textwidth}{.1\textwidth}
  \color{white}
  \inputminted[bgcolor=black]{python}{mybigscript.py}
\end{adjustwidth}
```

Comment: The result good but I have this warning `Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) detected at line`.